# How to fix arrayList image color text error?

Tags: android

**com.sk.recyclerviewwithgridview public static final class drawable
extends** Object This error is causing me.How should I fix this error I don't know how to fix this

As you can see the screenshort are silk to give

Link[image: Link]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got [this](https://github.com/sambhaji213/Recyclerview-with-Gridview/commit/baa37b8abf94f47aae882ec229e56222c06cbed0) code  and hope you've imported the code perfectly

Use this code in oncreateview

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
        Toolbar toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        arrayList = new ArrayList<Item>();
        arrayList.add(new Item("Item 1", R.drawable.battle, ""));
        arrayList.add(new Item("Item 2", R.drawable.beer, "#3E51B1"));
        arrayList.add(new Item("Item 3", R.drawable.ferrari, "#673BB7"));
        arrayList.add(new Item("Item 4", R.drawable.jetpack_joyride, "#4BAA50"));
        arrayList.add(new Item("Item 5", R.drawable.three_d, "#F94336"));
        arrayList.add(new Item("Item 6", R.drawable.terraria, "#0A9B88"));

        HomeAdapter adapter = new HomeAdapter(getActivity(), arrayList, (HomeAdapter.ItemListener) getActivity());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        GridLayoutManager manager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2, VERTICAL, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
        return view;
    }
```

Here's full overlay fragment

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import static androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager.*;

public class OverlayFragment extends Fragment implements HomeAdapter.ItemListener{
    View view;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ArrayList<Item> arrayList;

    public static com.rad.mls.OverlayFragment newInstance() {
        return new com.rad.mls.OverlayFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
        Toolbar toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        arrayList = new ArrayList<Item>();
        arrayList.add(new Item("Item 1", R.drawable.battle, ""));
        arrayList.add(new Item("Item 2", R.drawable.beer, "#3E51B1"));
        arrayList.add(new Item("Item 3", R.drawable.ferrari, "#673BB7"));
        arrayList.add(new Item("Item 4", R.drawable.jetpack_joyride, "#4BAA50"));
        arrayList.add(new Item("Item 5", R.drawable.three_d, "#F94336"));
        arrayList.add(new Item("Item 6", R.drawable.terraria, "#0A9B88"));

        HomeAdapter adapter = new HomeAdapter(getActivity(), arrayList, (HomeAdapter.ItemListener) getActivity());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        GridLayoutManager manager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2, VERTICAL, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflate) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflate);
        getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(Item item) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), item.text + " is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: @atozcodescom  wrote one ! , check it